# Why does show() only work for a split second?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have the list items appear on click. When I use the hide() method they start off hidden, but when I add the show() method, it only works for about a a millisecond. Not sure if it is because it always defaults back to the original setting? I basically just want to click the main list `<a>` in this case Main List and have the other two appear

```js
$(function() {
  $('.sublist').hide();
  $(".mainlist").on('click', function() {
    $('.sublist').show();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="" class="mainlist">Main List</a>
    <li>
      <a href="" class="sublist">Sublist One</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" class="sublist">Sublist Two</a>
    </li>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: First of all your HTML is invalid, you are using nested `li's` inside `li`

Comment: Your simplified example works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/1a9t230b/. Maybe something else is going on in your application

Comment: I am not sure why it wasn't working in my editor but i do see it working in your example, thank you.

Comment: After seeing other's answers I noticed it's because of a slight change I made to the example. Using `href="#"` for the links. That will prevent the anchors from reloading the page. It's the more common approach I see, but other answers will work as well

Answer (score 2):

When you click the link the Whole page refreshes. This Means that your code runs Again:

```
$('.sublist').hide();
```

What you should do is prevent default behavior like this:

```
$(".mainlist").on('click', function(event) {
      $('.sublist').show();
      event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: sorry about that, appreciate the feedback

Comment: @Cnote Check out the working snippet I posted... `:)`

Comment: @Stijn  it could be.  the OP may not be mentioning the page refresh, and since the default behaviour is to hide it, it could show for a brief moment, the page reloads, and it's hidden again.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your page is getting reloaded when you click those `a` elements, because of the `href=""` on them. So the divs start out hidden, then clicking shows them, but then the page refreshes and they're back to being hidden again (since that's their default state on a freshly-loaded page, thanks to the `hide` call in your page-ready callback).

If you don't want those links to be followed, prevent the default action when they're clicked via `preventDefault` (or `return false`) in a jQuery handler:

```
$(function() {
  $('.sublist').hide();
    $(".mainlist").on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.sublist').show(); 
    }); 
})
```

Live Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.sublist').hide();
    $(".mainlist").on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.sublist').show(); 
    }); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="mainlist">Main List</a>
        <li>
          <a href="" class="sublist">Sublist One</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="sublist">Sublist Two</a>
      </li>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Alternately, there's a hack you can use: `href="javascript:;"`, but it's preferable to make the links meaningful, and then use script to provide that meaning.

---

Separately: You can't have an [`li`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-li-element) directly inside another `li` like that, you need another [`ul`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-ul-element) (or `ol`) in there. See those links for details.

Comment: @Stijn - Right -- the click handler shows them, and then the page loads, and they're hidden again (because that's the default page state). So....?

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues:

First, you have `li` elements nested directly inside `li` elements - if you want a "sub-list", you need to wrap the sub-items inside a `ul` (see modified code below).

Second, the link is being followed, which is causing the page to refresh.  If ALL you want to have happen is the `sublist` items to show, then you should use [event.preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) on the event (see modified code below).

```js
// no-conflict safe document ready
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.sublist').hide();
  // click event accepts one argument for the "event"
  $(".mainlist").on('click', function(e) {
    // prevent the default "click" action (which is to load the url the link points to)
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.sublist').show();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="" class="mainlist">Main List</a>
    <!-- nested li elements need to be wrapped inside a ul -->
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="sublist">Sublist One</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="sublist">Sublist Two</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using anchor `a` tag, and there is an empty `href` attribute, the default behavior should be to redirect the page on anchor click. The fix to this is to either use `href="javascript:void(0)"` or `event.preventDefault()` within the click callback

```js
$(function() {
    $('.sublist').hide()
    $(".mainlist").on('click', function(e) {
      /* here, prevents redirection */
      if (e) { e.preventDefault() }
      $('.sublist').show()
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="mainlist">Main List</a>
    <li>
      <a href="" class="sublist">Sublist One</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" class="sublist">Sublist Two</a>
    </li>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

This part of your code :

```
$(".mainlist").on('click', function() {
  $('.sublist').show(); 
});
```

Is telling to show the list only during the click event.

Why not using the fadeIn() effects function instead ?

```js
 $( "#appears" ).hide();
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#appears" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
 
   <div id="clickme">
    Click here
    </div>

    <div id="appears">
      <ul>
        <li>I'm a list</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this works, this doesn't actually solve OP's problem / answer their specific question.  Would be good if you were to address the issues in OP's original code before proposing a completely different method....

Comment: I'm not deleting my answer but I see what you means and I agree that your solution stick more with the original issue.